# Can I use my Olympus E-10 lenses on my Canon T3i?

Tags: lens, canon, olympus, compatibility

I just bought a Canon Rebel T3i but would like to also use my Wide angle, Micro,Macro and telephoto lenses from my Olympus E-10, Is it just a matter of a step ring from 58mm to 62mm?

Answer (score 1):

It may be physically possible, but there's the question of if you really want to. IIRC, the E-10 accessory lenses will have been optimized for the E-10's lens. Using them on other lenses will probably give poor results. But hey, a step up ring is only a couple of bucks, so go ahead and try, and let us know how it worked out. BTW, I think the macro lens will do quite well, because it's basically the same thing as close up lenses offered by several manufacturers for SLRs.

Answer (score 0):

The Olympus E-10 is not a system camera since its lens is fixed to the body. I guess that your wide angle, micro, macro and telephoto lenses are all of the screw on type for the lens filter thread since you mention the step ring. If so you can use them with other lenses on other cameras.

The fact that you want to use them specifically on the Canon T3i is not important. The problem is the filter thread size om the lens mounted on the camera. It it's a 62 mm thread then just go for it otherwise you have to use a step ring as you suggested. Going from a smaller filer to a larger is not usually a problem (the other way around may be) so you should be fine.

There are however one more problem to take into account. The sensor size of the Olympus E-10 is 2/3" and the Canon T3i has a APS-C sized one. This means that the filter add on lenses you've got may fill just a part of the frame of the sensor in the Canon T3i and you'll get a dark border in the photo.

You may also have problems with the Canon lens not being designed to use these add on lenses having trouble to focus etc.

My suggestion is to just try it. Lens filter step rings are not expensive and it may or may not work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is only matter of a step-up ring.

If you want to try before buying a thing, do a hand-held test. It is really easy and strightforward, specially if you have a tripod, but if you don't, a table and a bean bag is just fine.

Set up your new camera in any mode you wish, and make a few test shots to have a base to compare. Then hand-hold the filters lightly pressing them against the front border of your lens. (Lightly, very liaghtly, just enough to prevent movement.) Just be careful that your filters don't touch the front **glass** of the lens.

If you keep the filters and adapters fairly stable while shooting, you'll get a pretty good idea of what to expect when using a step-up ring. In this tests the distortion you can introduce are some movement blur, or if you don't properly center the filter or tilt it you can cause small deformities in the image, but I assure you they would be pretty minimal.

With this test you can know for sure if the new camera can focus though them and you will now for sure if the filters will cause vigneting or not. Enable autofocus in your camera/lens to be sure if autofocus works with the filters in front.